# C# Interop Based Application Slows in For-Loop

Tags: c#, excel, for-loop, ms-word, office-interop

This may be a little odd of an issue. Currently I am attempting to test some code I've written for transferring large documents from Microsoft Word to Microsoft Excel using Interop methods. My program relies on reading words from words and importing them into cells in excel. These documents can vary in length but some are quite long. I've found that the loop my program uses always starts off great and after a few thousand words and a few hundred cells the entire program slows. For example I was able to run through a quarter of this example document in 10 minutes but the entire document took hours to complete.

I guess what I am wondering is if this is an issue within my loop that is storing unnecessary data causing the slowing or if this is an issue on the Microsoft application side? I've tried inputting words as entire passages rather individual words and attempted inputting individual characters but neither provided a faster option. If possibly reloading the file or breaking from the loop would cause haste I would attempt that next, but just with my limited knowledge I'm feeling this is an issue on the Microsoft side.

Attached is the code for the loop.

```cs
for (int i = 1; i <= (docs.Words.Count); i++)
            {
                if (docs.Words[i].Text == "\r")
                {
                    if (i != 1 && docs.Words[i - 1].Text != "\r")
                    {
                        if (Math.Floor(count / 13) == 0)
                        {
                            count = count + 15;
                        }
                        wks.Cells[r,c].RowHeight = Math.Floor(count / 13) * 16; 
                        count = 0;
                        r++;
                        wks.Range[wks.Cells[r, 1], wks.Cells[r, 9]].Merge();
                    }
                }
                else if (docs.Words[i].Text == "\r\a")
                {
                    if (i != 1 && docs.Words[i - 1].Text == "\r\a")
                    {
                        if (Math.Floor(count/13) == 0)
                        {
                            count = count + 13;
                        }
                        wks.Cells[r, c].RowHeight = Math.Floor(count / 13) * 16; 
                        count = 0;
                        r++;
                        c = 1;
                        wks.Range[wks.Cells[r, 1], wks.Cells[r, 9]].Merge();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        wks.Range[wks.Cells[r, 1], wks.Cells[r, 9]].Unmerge();
                        c++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        wks.Cells[r, c].Value2 = wks.Cells[r, c].Value2 + docs.Words[i].Text;
                        Console.WriteLine((docs.Words.Count - count2).ToString());
                        count++;
                        count2++;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thank you for any help provided. If an answer isn't received soon I'll most likely remove the question and proceed with the slower option. This is less a catastrophic matter just a question of convivences.

Comment: Have you tried using GC.Collect? It might be worth using it every 1000 lines or so.

Comment: I have not. My knowledge of garbage collection is rough but don't applications automatically collect said garbage during runtime? I'll toss it in anyway and see if anything comes of it.

Comment: Take a look at CloseXML: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML . There you write an excel-file. That far more faster than using interop.

Comment: I was hoping to use interop just to keep consistency with a few other applications I've put together, but I figure if processing might take hours to finish I may have to attempt the switch.